# Rearranging appended html with jquery

Tags: html, jquery

I have created a simple read more function with jquery which shows and hides text that is over a number of characters. It works fine however I have used some open source code and I would like to understand further how to rearrange the html which is being generated. Firstly I would like the button to be under the text. So the span with the class hidden appears before the button, thus not dropping the text onto a separate line. I would also like to add '...' before this hidden span, and at the end of the visible text. When I have tried moving the line that appends the span with the class hidden, this text goes inside the button.

https://jsfiddle.net/w4j5rhme/

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function () {
      var maxL = 150;

      jQuery('.outer-card-expand p').each(function () {

          var text = jQuery(this).text();
          if(text.length > maxL) {

              var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                  end = text.substr(maxL);

              jQuery(this).html(begin)
                  .append(jQuery('<div class="see-more see-more-closed"></div>').html(''))
                  .append(jQuery('<span class="hidden">').html(end))
          }
      });

      jQuery(document).on('click', '.see-more', function () {
          jQuery(this).next('.hidden').slideToggle(400);
      })        
  })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, here is the modified script that worked for me in Edge, Firefox and Chrome

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
  jQuery(function () {
      
    var maxL = 150;

      jQuery('.outer-card-expand p').each(function () {

          var text = jQuery(this).text();
          if(text.length > maxL) {

              var begin = text.substr(0, maxL),
                  end = text.substr(maxL);

              jQuery(this).html(begin)
                .append('<span class="read-more">...</span>')
                .append(jQuery('<span class="hidden">').html(end))
                .append(jQuery('<div class="see-more see-more-closed"></div>').html(''))

          }
      });

      jQuery(document).on('click', '.see-more', function () {
        jQuery('.hidden').slideToggle(400);
        jQuery('.read-more').toggle('hidden');
      })        
  })
});
```

The two changes are

1. The order chaining `.append` functions have been switched and a span to indicate more text has been added
2. apply `.slideToggle` directly to the hidden span, as well as toggling visibility on `<span class="read-more">...</span>`